# How did Diamond Jozu lose his arm?

Tags: one-piece

I have read in the wiki that Jozu's right arm was missing after the war. But I have never seen nor notice it in the anime.

And I can't find the part where he lost it.

So when and how did he lose his arm and who was he fighting with??

Comment: If his arm is not shown actually being shattered in the manga nor the anime than we can't conclude that he lost his arm. If you listen to the sound effects of the anime nothing shatered. It sounds like a rock hit the ground. he most likely used his ability under the ice. just like whitebeard freed himself of the ice with his quake fruit. Or mingo's haki freed himself from freezing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLZ6uk2Wwug) from the MarineFord War which shows that he lost his arm to Aokiji.
While fighting Aokiji, his attention goes towards Marco and Aokiji takes advantage of this and uses his devil fruit power to make him freeze.

Comment: It shows that he was frozen, but I can't see where he lost his arm. Is it when he fell down?

Comment: Yep, thats the only thing revealed. Now its upto Oda sensei to answer your question :P

Comment: We can deduce that : Jozu's Weight + His Frozen Arm + Gravity = His broken arm :P

Comment: I guess that can only be the reason for now. Thanks for the clip.

Comment: @NixR.Eyes Look carefully to his right arm instead of his left, it dislogdes the moment he hits the floor. [here](http://img4.mangasee.co/series/OnePiece/0569-006.png) is the manga occurrence, where you can clearly see his right arm has been separated from his body.

Answer (score 0):

He lost his arms during the Payback war,  a clash between the remnants of the Whitebeard Pirates — under Marco's leadership — and the Blackbeard Pirates about a year after the Battle of Marineford.

Comment: Do you have sources to back that up?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happen in anime but on manga it was pretty clear that Aokiji freeze him and broke his arm.

On The Marineford Arc chapter 568 and 569, when Shirohige down because of his sickness, most of his crew are getting distracted and the marine took an advantage and attack both Marco and Jozu.

[image: One Piece chapter 569 Monster Page 7]